# How do I exclude a method call from verification?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, moq-3

I am using Moq and set up some expectations in the TestInitialize method as so:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void init()
{
    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.EventDefinitions).Returns(ListsOfEvents.EventDefinitions);
    mockRepo.Setup(x => x.EventTypes).Returns(ListsOfEvents.EventTypes);
}
```

I don't care if these are called or not so I don't want the `VerifyAll()` to throw an exception for these.

What's the magic combination of letters I need to type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use `VerfiyAll()` then. Just use `Verify()` on the calls you do care about.

Comment: Seems obvious, with hindsight!